# "Not defined variable" in a 'while loop' in Julia

Tags: while-loop, julia, julia-jump

I am trying to do a sensitivity analysis in Julia using `JuMP`. Here is my code:
using JuMP, Plots, Gurobi

```
m=Model(with_optimizer(Gurobi.Optimizer))


@variable(m, x>=0)
@variable(m, y>=0)
@variable(m, k>=0)

k = 0

while k<=1
    φ(x,y,k)=3*x+k*y

    @objective(m, Max, φ(x,y,k))

    @constraint(m, 2*x-4>=0)
    @constraint(m, y-0.5*x>=0)

    pl=optimize!(m)
    k=k+0.2
end
```

The problem is that I get an error:

> UndefVarError: k not defined

What am I missing?

Comment: alternatively, you can use the `Clp` solver instead of the `Gurobi` solver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
julia> k =0
0

julia> while k<10
           k=k+1
       end
ERROR: UndefVarError: k not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at ./REPL[11]:2
```

In julia if we are operating with loops the variables we initialise outside our loop can not be directly accessed within a loop on default. To do that we have to set those variable on to global use as on default they are considered to be local

```
julia> while k<10
         global  k=k+1
       end
```

**Now this works fine**

Comment: could you be more detailed?

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: This is an alternative solution, that it was suggested by a member of Julia Discorse*

In a discussion at [Julia Discourse](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/save-objective-values-in-an-optimization-loop/33192), it is suggested to wrap the code in a function in order to increase speed and to avoid the `global` issue:

```
function run_code()
    model = Model(with_optimizer(Gurobi.Optimizer))
    @variable(model, x >= 0)
    @variable(model, y >= 0)
    @constraint(model, 2x - 4 >= 0)

    k = 0

    while k <= 1
        @objective(model, Max, 3x + k * y)
        optimize!(model)
        k = k + 0.2
    end
end
run_code()
```